# Nomenclature not showing using vimtex / latexmk compilation set-up

Tags: latexmk, nomenclature, vim, nomencl

I would like to include a list of symbols in my notes and am trying to do this using the nomencl package. Unfortunately, I can't get it to appear. I don't any error messages, but also no output. My compilation set-up is vimtex based with latexmk and I would like to know how to incorporate it in that. An abbreviated version of my problem is below. Main.tex provides the main document and latex.lua is my vimtex set-up in neovim, while latexmkrc are my latexmk settings. I am sure a number of improvements are possible, but browsing several tutorials and related questions have not yet led to a solution. Any thoughts?

main.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{M}{Mathematical symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}}%
]}

\nomenclature[M]{\(\RR\)}{Real numbers}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

latex.lua

```
vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
  background = 1,
  build_dir = 'build',
  callback = 1,
  executable = 'latexmk',
  options = {
    '-xelatex',
    '-synctex=1',
    '-interaction=nonstopmode',
    '-shell-escape',
  },
}
```

.latexmkrc

```
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo gls 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'glo');

$pdflatex = 'xelatex -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -file-line-error %O
```

Comment: Try running `latexmk` and making your `makeindex` call on the command line, an up-to-date `nomencl` should be generating a `.nlo` from tex which should generate `.nls` from `makeindex`. I guess `latexmk` sees no `.glo` so doesn't attempt the `makeindex`.

Comment: If I run makeindex manually on the .nlo file it creates the nls file and I have the nomenclature. How to automate this?

Comment: Presumably all instances of `glo` and `gls` in your `.latexmkrc` should be `nlo` and `nls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main.tex` has an error, the line
`\ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}}%`
has an extra `}` at the end and should be
`\ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}%`.
`\RR` is also not defined, so I've added `\newcommand\RR{RR}` but probably you want to load a package.

Your `.latexmkrc` appears to have a dodgy `$pdflatex` call, we also want to replace the `glo` and `gls` with `nlo` and `nls` as

```
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "nlo nls 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'nlo');
    
$pdflatex = 'xelatex --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --file-line-error %O %S'
```

This then compiles on the command line with `latexmk -pdf main.tex` (requiring `-pdf` as otherwise `latexmk` appears to default to `latex`).

I don't think this `$pdflatex` line is the preferred way to call `xelatex` though, it overwrites `latexmk`'s `pdflatex` and hardcodes flags (fixing `--shell-escape` active is not a great idea).  You can just do

```
latexmk -xelatex [flag options to xelatex] file
```

I haven't tested with neovim/vimtex, but it looks like your `latex.lua` does exactly that, in which case

main.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\newcommand\RR{RR}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{M}{Mathematical symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}%
]}

\nomenclature[M]{\(\RR\)}{Real numbers}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

.latexmkrc

```
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "nlo nls 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'nlo');
```

should work if you trigger compilation within vimtex.  If this doesn't work, try without `build_dir = 'build',` in `latex.lua` first, the `makeindex` call may need to be adapted to take account of the `build_dir`.